# How to use txtV1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bcgrtxt));`in Older Devices?

Tags: android, textview, setbackground

How to use

```
txtV1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bcgrtxt));
```

in Older Devices ?

Comment: what's the error? logcat?

Comment: No Errors But I need a way to set Image as a background to the TextView without add this line to my code "@SuppressLint("NewApi")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.setBackground` was added in **API Level 16**

and `.setBackgroundResource` was added in **API Level 1**

so you can use `.setBackgroundResource` instead of `.setBackground`

Answer (score 1):

`View.setBackground` replaced [`View.setBackgroundDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) as of API level 16.